# Is it proper for unit tests to use premade files?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for my Java program. My program does a lot of things that involve reading from a file that the user inputs and creating a new file based on the contents of the inputted file.

Currently, my unit tests are using premade files made for testing that I've placed in the resources source directory. When it creates a file, it places it in the same resources source directory.

I've looked at a lot of questions and answers on here, and there are so many varying opinions on how to handle files in unit tests. Is it proper to use these premade files within my unit tests, or is there a better solution?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine. But don't put files generated by your tests under src. They're not sources, so they have nothing to do in src.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. I will change where they are getting created.

Comment: You could also refactor the code to take just an `InputStream` instead of a `FileInputStream` and then just pass a `ByteArrayInputStream` and keep everything in a test. (Same thing for writing files: use `OutputStream` and such.) If you pass file names instead, there's a bit more to refactor, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the standard practice is to place your static input files for testing in the `src/test/resources` directory.  If you main code generates output, the cleanest place to put it during testing is in your platform-specific tmp directory.  In Java, this is under the System property `java.io.tmpdir`:

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));`

If you use this directory, it will be portable between developers running it under MacOS, Linux, or Windows - as well as any build server.

It is also a good idea for your test to delete these temporary files when the test is complete, and for your test to not make any assumption about temporary files that may exist from a previous test run.

Comment: For the temporary files, also have a look at JUnit's `TemporaryFolder` Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not static "premade" files are appropriate largely depends on the logic you're trying to test and how you want to manage your test data. Perhaps you need test data that contains a date that is relative to today's date. In this case using a static file could be more trouble than writing code to calculate a relative date.

As JB Nizet pointed out in his comment it's generally not a good idea to store test data alongside your source code. I'm not sure if you're familiar with maven and its [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) but you might take a look at it and see how it helps keep the test and source files separated.

Comment: Good point on with the possibility of the file needing something like today's date. I don't currently have anything like that in my program, but it is good to keep in mind.